# Is there a maximum file size limit that can be read with scipy.io.readsav?

Tags: python, scipy

Summary: I have a 3D FLOAT array with 905 x 905 x 762 elements. It is stored in an IDL save file that cannot be read with `scipy.io.readsav`. When I store part of this array (905 x 905 x 600 elements or less) in another IDL save file, this time `scipy.io.readsav` works fine.

This is what I do to read any of these two files:

```
from scipy.io import readsav
filename = 'datacube.sav'
sav = readsav(filename, verbose=True)
```

And this is the error I get when I read the larger IDL save file:

```
/Users/moncho/Codes/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/idl.py:473: UserWarning: Using experimental 64-bit array read
warnings.warn("Using experimental 64-bit array read")
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-c6753cefbd81>", line 1, in <module> runfile('/Users/moncho/Data/untitled7.py', wdir='/Users/moncho/Data')
File "/Users/moncho/Codes/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/Users/moncho/Codes/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "/Users/moncho/Data/untitled7.py", line 11, in <module>
sav = readsav(filename, verbose=True)
File "/Users/moncho/Codes/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/idl.py", line 799, in readsav
r = _read_record(f)
File "/Users/moncho/Codes/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/idl.py", line 360, in _read_record
rectypedesc['array_desc'])
File "/Users/moncho/Codes/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/idl.py", line 284, in _read_array
array = np.fromstring(f.read(array_desc['nbytes']),

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I am running python 3.5 on a Mac OS X 10.11.6. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loading a file depends on the amount of free memory available in the system. Verify if you have sufficient memory available. Experienced a similar case before - I was able to load large files using scipy in 2.7 OS X but not in 3.5. Try *readsav* in 2.7. This is a bug.

Comment: Rane thanks for your answer. I have checked the memory issue and this is not the problem here, so maybe this is a bug, as you mention. I am very new to python and so I need to check how to run python 2.7. Right now I only have 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this post was edited but I ran into a similar problem (reading a large IDL cube into memory) using Pyton 3.7 & Scipy 1.7.1.
Posting my solution here if someone else runs into a similar issue.

In my case, the issue might come from `io.BufferedReader.read`.
Looking on the internet, I found this issue which could be related to ours:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3858

Updating to the latest Python (3.9.5) and numpy (1.21.2) seems to have fixed it but I can't tell whether its the Python or numpy version which fixed it.

Hope this can help someone one day.